# What is 'objects' in e=Emp.objects.all() in django Models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

If `Emp` is a Model in in Django, I can do

```
  e = Emp.objects.all()
```

where

> `e` : refers to a query set
>
> `Emp` : represents a model name
>
> `all()` : is being used to get all columns from table

But what is `objects` ?

Please explain in depth what data type `objects` is in this query, and how it is used.

Comment: plz help am New in django and python .

Comment: So why don't you read the tutorial, where all this is explained?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/managers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a model manager. Here are the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/managers/) on it.

From the docs:

> A Manager is the interface through which database query operations are provided to Django models. At least one Manager exists for every model in a Django application.